# _CtrlsValidHeapPointer(Block)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, data-structures, linked-list

I'm new to c++ and I use c++ to learn data structure recently. I stuck when the error occurs, I've tried to debug but It's still confused me. So, this error is I try to implement two operations concatenate and merge, my terminal shows the result that seems to successful on logical. However, the error is coming in the next second.
Just like img:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xbnE.jpg) [call stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwyU9.jpg)

Here is my code. Hopefully, someone can help me solve this issue, thanks!

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class LinkedList;
class Node
{
private:
    int data;
    Node* next;
public:
    friend class LinkedList;
};

class LinkedList
{
private:
    Node* first;
    Node* last;
    Node* third;
public:
    LinkedList()
    {
        first = nullptr;
        last = nullptr;
        third = nullptr;
    }
    LinkedList(int A[], int n);
    ~LinkedList();
    void Display();
    void RDisplay();//Recursive
    void RDisplay(Node* p);
    Node* getFirstNode();
    int Count();
    int RCount(Node* p);//Recursive
    int Sum();
    int RSum(Node* p);//Recursive
    int Max();
    int RMax(Node* p);//Recursive
    int LSearch(int key); //linear search
    int RSearch(int key);
    int RSearch(Node* p, int key);
    void Insert(int position, int x);
    void InsertLast(int x);
    void SortedInsert(int x);
    int Delete(int position);
    int isSorted();
    void RemoveDuplicate();
    void ReverseE();//Elements
    void ReverseL();//Links
    void RReverse();//Recursive
    void RReverse(Node* q,Node *p);
    void Concatenate(Node* second);
    void Merge(Node *second);
    int Mid();
    int isLoop();
};
```

```
//cpp file
#include "Linkedlist.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
LinkedList::LinkedList(int A[], int n)
{
    Node* t ;
    first = new Node;
    first->data = A[0];
    first -> next = nullptr;
    last = first;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        t = new Node;
        t->data = A[i];
        t->next = nullptr;
        last->next = t;
        last = t;
    }
}

LinkedList ::~LinkedList()
{
    Node* p = first;
    while (first)
    {
        first = first->next;
        delete p;
        p = first;
    }
}

void LinkedList::Merge(Node* second)
{
    Node* last;
    if (first->data < second->data)
    {
        third =  first;
        last = first;
        first = first->next;
        last->next = nullptr;
    }
    else
    {
        third = last = second;
        second = second->next;
        last->next = NULL;
    }
    while (first != NULL && second != NULL)
    {
        if (first->data < second->data)
        {
            last->next = first;
            last = first;
            first = first->next;
            last->next = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            last->next = second;
            last = second;
            second = second->next;
            last->next = NULL;
        }
    }
    if (first != NULL)
    {
        last->next = first;
        first = third;
    }
    else
    {
        last->next = second;
        first = third;
    }
}

//concatenate
void LinkedList::Concatenate(Node* second)
{
    Node* p = first;
    while (p->next != NULL)
    {
        p = p->next;
    }
    p->next = second;
}

void LinkedList::Display()
{
    Node* p = first;
    while (p != nullptr)
    {
        cout << p->data << " -> ";
        p = p->next;
    }
}


Node* LinkedList::getFirstNode()
{
    return first;
}
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Linkedlist.h"
#include "Circular.h"
#include "Doubly.h"
#include "CircularDoubly.h"

int main()
{
    int A[] = { 1,2,3,4,6,7 };
    int B[] = { 5,6,7,8 };
    LinkedList c1(A,6);
    LinkedList c2(B, 4);
    c1.Concatenate(c2.getFirstNode());
    c1.Display();
}
```

Should I offer more detail?

[stack call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0AaHS.jpg)
[stack call2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WzR0.jpg)

Comment: Seems some files not pasted here. Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Sorry, my English is not good, I've added a constructor and display function, did you mean that?

Comment: You need to click 重试 and try to debug it, at least to paste the call stack here, your program has memory issues.

Comment: ok, I will try it later and paste it here, thank you!

Comment: And your destructor is not pasted here, please update it.

Comment: I have class now, when I after class I will try it and update thanks!

Comment: I've added destructor and pasted call stack, I found the problem is in destructor, but I can't understand why it error... is either the pinter "last" or it has two linked list but just destructor only 1... I guess

Comment: You attach the nodes of `c2` onto `c1`, but leave them in `c2` as well. This will cause them to be deleted twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's the problem in destructor, after `Concatenate`, the `c2` list has been appended to `c1` list, the elements are destroyed twice, once in `c1`'s destructor, the second time in `c2`'s destructor. This is a memory issue that may lead to a crash.

I suggest fix it like this:
Transfer the ownership to `c1`, then we avoid destroy twice

```cpp
Node* LinkedList::ReleaseFirst() {
  Node* tmp = first;
  first = nullptr;
  return tmp;
}
```

```cpp
c1.Concatenate(c2.ReleaseFirst());
```

[Online demo](https://godbolt.org/z/1Y8jn4Yrv)